# How to open atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm new to atom (atom.io), I have downloaded it, and success installed it. But how to open this editor?

There is no shortcut in my desktop. And no atom icon on my start menu.
How to open this editor?

Comment: Click on "All Programs" from start menu or press "Windows" key then type 'atom' to search for atom.

Comment: i have done with that trick, and no atom found, i used windows 10

Answer (score 12):

If you are using windows check:

```
C:\Users\<yourUserName>\AppData\Local\atom
```

Answer (score 1):

Atom SETTINGS -> System: tab -> Checked two options: 
- Show in file context menus
- Show in folder context menus

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First go to this location

```
C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Local\atom
```

In my case YOURUSERNAME is hp. After going to that folder check the file name atom with atom symbol of type application.

[Click on the link below to see the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuQjO.png)

After that, right click that file and click the option create shortcut. Then move the shortcut to your Desktop.
Now you can access/open atom editor from your desktop.

ENJOY!

Answer (score 0):

```
cd C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Local\atom
start atom.exe
```

Just copy this code to a notepad file and save it as `Atom.bat` on your desktop. I know it is a workaround, but hey, it works!
You can customize the icon too if you want by going to it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please unhide "hidden files"
2. Find on this location [AppData is a hidden folder in windows10]

   C:\Users<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Local\atom

Answer (score 0):

It's in "[GitHub, Inc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHbHU.png)" folder in start menu.
If there isn't, go to `C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Local\atom` or
`C:\Users\<YOURUSERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\GitHub, Inc`

If these do not work, reinstall it! and after it finished try to pin it on Taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the Atom app settings as described here: [https://atom.io/packages/settings-view#:~:text=Usage,File%20%3E%20Settings%20(Windows)](https://atom.io/packages/settings-view#:%7E:text=Usage,File%20%3E%20Settings%20(Windows)).

"You can open the Settings View by navigating to Edit > Preferences (Linux), Atom > Preferences (macOS), or File > Settings (Windows)."

For windows computer: On the Atom app home screen click on File, then settings. You then scroll to System settings and select all the check boxes as shown in one of the images in the answers in this thread.

After completing these steps you will notice that if you right click on any of your files, and click "open with" Atom will be one of the options to open your file with. After opening Atom you can right click the icon on your task bar and click "pin to task bar" and use that as your shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, I actually just found it in

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\local\atom\atom.exe
```

It was installed by chocolatey;  perhaps that affected the install location?  On a different system chocolatey installed it in a more normal place.